# Java play 1.2.5 - Reverse routing to subpackage of controllers

Tags: java, playframework, routes, playframework-1.x

Is it possible to put a controller from package controllers to package controllers.subpackage and get the reverse routing in play 1.2.5 working?

Adding

```
GET     /myMethod           controllers.subpackage.MyController.myMethod
```

to conf/routes works fine but if I call

```
Router.reverse("controllers.subpackage.MyController.myMethod")
```

in Application.java it fails to compile, saying "No route found".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact your route definition should be :

```
GET     /myMethod           subpackage.MyController.myMethod
```

and then the reverse will be fine

```
Router.reverse("subpackage.MyController.myMethod")
```